# org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: for google search

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to enter Mobile Phones in the Google search but the below code fails at place  when sending Mobile phones at the search. I used the below xpath. Please see the error at end of mail.

I even tried other xpaths as below:

```
html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/form/fieldset[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/input[3]

//div[@id='gs_lc0']/input[@id='gs_htif0']


public class exercise1 {

    @Test
    public void googleExercise() throws InterruptedException    {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://google.com");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gs_tti0']")).sendKeys("Mobile Phones");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gbqfba']']")).click();
        List<WebElement> alllinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        System.out.println(alllinks.size());
        for (int i=0;i<alllinks.size();i++) {
            System.out.println("Link " + i + " = " + alllinks.get(i).getText() + " = " + alllinks.get(i).isDisplayed());
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting below error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: Element is disabled and so may not be used for actions
Command duration or timeout: 46 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.37.0', revision: 'a7c61cb', time: '2013-10-18 17:15:02'
System info: host: 'ACHAYAPA-LAP', ip: '10.177.147.32', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_25'
Session ID: 37b84f2c-0735-4a6b-93e0-329bd2760c39
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, databaseEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=firefox, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=17.0.11}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:89)
    at exercise1.googleExercise(exercise1.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Element is disabled and so may not be used for actions
Build info: version: '2.37.0', revision: 'a7c61cb', time: '2013-10-18 17:15:02'
System info: host: 'ACHAYAPA-LAP', ip: '10.177.147.32', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_25'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.preconditions.enabled(file:///C:/Users/achayapa/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous4609315224719991191webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:8216)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.checkPreconditions_(file:///C:/Users/achayapa/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous4609315224719991191webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10827)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/achayapa/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous4609315224719991191webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10844)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.executeInternal_(file:///C:/Users/achayapa/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous4609315224719991191webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10849)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.execute/<(file:///C:/Users/achayapa/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous4609315224719991191webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10791)
```

Answer (score 0):

See, if this might help,

```
@Test
public void googleExercise() throws InterruptedException {

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://google.com");
Thread.sleep(10000);
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Mobile Phones");
Thread.sleep(5000);
WebElement findElementsClass = firefoxDriver.findElement(By.className("gssb_m"));
List<WebElement> alllinks = findElementsClass.findElements(By.tagName("span"));
System.out.println(alllinks.size());
for (int i=0;i<alllinks.size();i++) {
    System.out.println("Link " + i + " = " + alllinks.get(i).getText() + " = " + alllinks.get(i).isDisplayed());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Testing with Google is horrible,i tried different ways to send some search text to google search text box using its id,xpath etc.
Every time getting element disabled and tests failing.
Finally changed find mechanism to 
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("some text");
This worked and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code heredriver.get("http://google.com");
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("selenium");
    driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();

    Thread.sleep(4000);

    String p1 = "//*[@id='rso']/div[2]/li[" ;
    String p2 = "]/div/h3/a";

    int i = 1;
    while(checkElementPresent(p1+i+p2))
    {
        String x = driver.findElement(By.xpath(p1+i+p2)).getText();
        System.out.println(x);

        i++;
    }

}

public static boolean checkElementPresent(String path)
{
    int count = driver.findElements(By.xpath(path)).size();

    if(count == 0)
    {
        return false;

    }

    else
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: try to be little more careful while testing on google sites.. but refer to the above code it wil surely help